# Can't change audio file format - python

Tags: python, file, audio, pydub

I'm creating a program for school that streams video and audio from youtube and displays them for a few clients at the same time.
For this, I need to change a file's format to .mp3 and I learned that I can do that with pydub AudioSegment, yet, I keep getting an error.

That's the code lines that bring the error:

```
original_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(original_name)
original_audio.export(new_name, format="mp3")
```

This is the error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it's lying?

Comment: the path is completely right.....

Comment: never allow spaces in filenames nor directory names ... fix that and try again ... supply the full path to your file not just relative path ... for example /my/full/path/to/mytune.mp3

Comment: Never had any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ffmpeg installed? AFAIK that is a requirement. You can download ffmpeg from here: http://ffmpeg.org

Put this in your script directory and everything should then work fine.

Comment: I really dont know how to install this, can you help me out?

Comment: You don't have to install, just download the EXE and put it in the same file as your `.py` file